# Euro symbol not allowed

Tags: informix

I have a problem with the euro (€) symbol insertion (or update, or load, or unload... anything) on informix. When I try to insert/update it just throws the error:
"SQL Error (-79716): System or internal error java.io.IOException: Code-set conversion function failed due to illegal sequence or invalid value."

So, from what I've been reading you have to change the database locale to one that supports those kind of symbols. But for that you have to export and import the database and that most likely will be disapproved by my manager.

So, is there any other way around this, like some kind of previous encoding or something? It doesn't have to be readable in informix. It just needs to store the information and then I can encode/decode on C#...

I thought of just replacing the symbol on storage and then replace it again when I get it. But it could generate all kinds of problems and it's not really an ellegant option.

Comment: What Informix version are you using? What is the locale of your database? What is the locale of your client application?

Comment: @LuísMarques, informix version is: IBM Informix Dynamic Server Version 11.70.FC8W1; Database and client locales are en_US.819.

Comment: As a solution I've put 'euro' to replace the € symbol. But that's only a half solution, because there are other symbols that it doesn't read. And if some time in the future the user decides to input one of them it will go boom again.

Comment: Well, [en_US.819](http://ascii-table.com/codepage.php?819) does not have the euro symbol, so how can your application send a `EURO` symbol? What I have seem around is applications that send utf-8 encoded strings into en_US.819 databases, which Informix will accept (with the "right" configuration), because it's all bytes, and then retrieve those strings as en_US.819 and do the "conversion" client side.This is not how it should be done.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I've read too. But the database was created with that locale and it's in production so that won't even be considered, as (as for what I've read) it requires exporting, droping and importing the database, which I don't see happening... I was looking for some kind of workaround for that. I know it isn't the best option by I have to have some alternative. Well, in the end I already have a solution, even if it isn't the one it should be. So, if there is no other better solution (other than what should have been done from the start) it isn't that big of a deal.